# in this program why is Thread[Two, 5, main] appearing before One: 5?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package javaapplication18;
class Alistair_Therein implements Runnable{
String name
     Thread t;
     Alistair_Therein(String threadname){
         name = threadname;
         t = new Thread(this, name);
         System.out.println("New thread:" + t);
         t.start();
     }
     public void run(){
         try{
             for(int i=5; i>0; i--){
                 System.out.println(name " : " + i);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
             }
         }catch(InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println(name + "interrupted");
         }
         System.out.println(name + "exiting");
     }


 }

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Alistair_Therein("One");
        new Alistair_Therein("Two");
        new Alistair_Therein("Three");
        try{

                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Main Thread interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
    }

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
New Thread: Thread[One, 5, main]
New Thread: Thread[Two, 5, main]
New Thread: Thread[Three, 5, main]
One: 5
Two: 5
Three: 5
One: 4
Two: 4
Three: 4
One: 3
Two: 3
Three: 3
One: 2
Two: 2
Three: 2
One: 1
Two: 1
Three: 1
One exiting.
Two exiting. 
Three exiting.
Main thread exiting.
```

Why is `Thread[Two, 5, main]` appearing before `One: 5`?

Answer (score 2):

There are no guarantees about what order you will see events in different threads occur, unless you use synchronization constructs.

*[In this particular instance, I'd guess that the overhead involved in initiating a thread is substantially greater than the overhead involved in initiating a new object, so the new object creation "wins".]*

Comment: then without using synchronization, what s the point of giving sleep? The author says its to make the main thread exit last?

Comment: @Abhay: On a fine-grained level, the two threads will "race" to complete.  But on a coarse-grained level, of course, a 10-second sleep will always finish after 5 1-second sleeps.  But don't try to use `sleep` instead of proper synchronization.

Comment: hmmm, ok sounds logical. it would be nice if you could find something substantial to back that up

Comment: @Abhay Saini Even if there's no explicit synchronization, we can be almost entirely sure that spawning three threads and having each of them count to 5 is going to take less than whatever the sleep duration is (I suspect that Thread.sleep() takes a milliseconds argument, so that would be 10 seconds).

Comment: but there are 3 5second sleep functions? woun't that make it 15

Comment: sorry guys for this late interjection, but then it means the main thread is inherently different than the threads created ? Because the sleep function for that does not occur concurrently with these three. And, are the threads created from the same class able to work concurrently? or all threads except main?

Comment: @Abhay: In your code, you have a total of four threads, each running concurrently and independently.  So I would expect to see a message from each of the three threads once per second 5 times in total, then the exit message from each of the three threads, then a delay of approximately 5 seconds, and then the exit message from the main thread.

Comment: when the control transfers from one place to another, time is not spent in that? coz, it shows everything in exact times

Comment: @Abhay: I'm not sure what you're asking.  There is some overhead involved in swapping between multiple threads; this will mean that some of the sleeps will start later than expected, so you will get some variation in the exact run-time of each thread.

Comment: ok, actually that was not noticeable in netbeans, anyway thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `start()` does **not** mean that the code in the `Runnable.run()` method of the newly created thread will start at *that precise moment*. It simply puts the thread into the runnable state and lets the scheduler decide when it will actually run.

It's very likely that the construction of all 3 `Thread` objects will run in one go before any of the newly created threads get to execute code.

Also note that printing to `System.out` (or `System.err`) forces synchronization to happen which can easily influence the outcome of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are designed to run concurrently and independently (this is the whole point).  The output of independent thread can occur in any order.

Comment: Its from a book, by Herbert Schildt

Comment: He uses sleep so you can see interleaved output.  Without the sleep, the first thread can complete before the second has even started and you might not see anything running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are printing the thread."Thread[One, 5, main]" it is printed as these are the details of thread.
"**One**" here points out thread name.
"**5**" here points out thread priority number.
"**main**" stands for thread group.
if you comment this line

> //   System.out.println("New thread:" + t);

Thread[One, 5, main] it won't appear.